# How perform calculation on a XAML Binding value: reverse it, multiply it, subtract from it or add to it?

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, converters

First; the question is rhetorical, I have an answer! I have gotten so much help from looking here that I wanted to give this neat trick back.

Imagine that you have a value that you want to bind to, but it is somehow or somewhat wrong.

- I had a situation where I wanted to bind to a value, but when the value was 1, I needed 0, and vice-versa.
- There was a time when I wanted to bind the width of an element to the width of a parent - 68px.

Comment: Nice broad-use idea for a converter. I'll keep this idea in mind. Most of the math that I've ever needed to do on bound values can be done using this one converter. My experience is in calling these either a linear transformation function or a first degree polynomial. I probably would name it a LinearTransformConverter.

Comment: You should post the answer as an actual answer instead of including it in the question.

Comment: It's also called "first degree function" in French... Well, everywhere, I guess :-D

Comment: Clever, but in most cases if you're using a value converter instead of view model logic you're probably making a mistake of some kind.  There are certainly plenty of exceptions to this (I'm sure, for instance, that there exist credible use cases for not having a view model, though I haven't seen one).  But my feeling is that value converters in general are a hack for injecting code into XAML, which makes this a hack for injecting code into a hack.

Comment: I realize its 8 years later, so perhaps clearer now, but I'll say it anyway: @RobertRossney - I strongly disagree. The principle "don't inject code into XAML" is more correctly stated "don't mix business/modeling logic with presentation logic". GUI systems that involve expressions, and even constraints, are 100% valid and appropriate - as long as the calculations are strictly for display purposes. The "limited" situation, where people end up doing those display-only calculations in their view model, because that is easier, is what is wrong.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/30708634/199364, which links to a couple of relevant nugets.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Enter the **FirstDegreeFunctionConverter**:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace GenericWPF
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Will return a*value + b
    /// </summary>
    public class FirstDegreeFunctionConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public double A { get; set; }
        public double B { get; set; }

        #region IValueConverter Members

        public object Convert( object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture )
        {
            double a = GetDoubleValue( parameter, A );

            double x = GetDoubleValue( value, 0.0 );

            return ( a * x ) + B;
        }

        public object ConvertBack( object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture )
        {
            double a = GetDoubleValue( parameter, A );

            double y = GetDoubleValue( value, 0.0 );

            return ( y - B ) / a;
        }

        #endregion


        private double GetDoubleValue( object parameter, double defaultValue )
        {
            double a;
            if( parameter != null )
                try
                {
                    a = System.Convert.ToDouble( parameter );
                }
                catch
                {
                    a = defaultValue;
                }
            else
                a = defaultValue;
            return a;
        }
    }
}
```

How to use it?

You make a resource for each use in the resource section:

```
<GenericWPF:FirstDegreeFunctionConverter x:Key="ReverseOne"
                            A="-1"
                            B="1" />

<Border Opacity="{Binding Path=Opacity
    , ElementName=daOtherField
    , Converter={StaticResource ReverseOne}}" />

<GenericWPF:FirstDegreeFunctionConverter x:Key="ListboxItemWidthToErrorWidth"
     A="1"
     B="-68" />

<TextBox MaxWidth="{Binding Path=ActualWidth
   , Converter={StaticResource ListboxItemWidthToErrorWidth}
   , RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}}" />
```

The name comes from the function y = a*x + b (Called a "first degree function" in Norwegian), and of course it would be possible to upgrade it to a second degree function y= a*x^2 + bx + c, but I haven't found a use for it yet.

I had a situation where I wanted to make columns based on width. Each time I got 200 pixels more width, I wanted the container to show me another column. At that time I hardcoded a converter, but I should have made a y=(a/x) + b converter instead.

Now, what should I have named this converter so that everybody understand what it is? Since I'm a Norwegian, I used the expression we learned in school, directly translated. Please, if you have a suggestion or an opinion, let me know.
Any refinements or improvements you have thought of would also be appreciated...

---

Maybe "**LinearTransformConverter**" would better communicate what the converter does for you, I'll think about it.
Any other proposals?
Tor

Comment: In case anyone runs into the problem of XAML not finding/accepting the class: Make sure that 1: It gets its own namespace (at least not the same as the main window/app), and 2: you refer to it by xmlns alias, set in the main window/page etc properties. For the namespace "ValueConverters", I added `xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:ValueConverters"` to my Window properties, then refered to it by using `<converters:FirstDegreeFunctionConverter x:Key="MultiplyByTwoThirds" A="0.6" B="0" />`, for example.

I don't know why it's fussy about a different namespace, but it wouldn't work without that

Comment: Also: You might have to restart for some errors to go away  -- maybe it's down to me using an older version of something in the chain, who knows

Answer (score 7):

What is even better is a `PolynomialConverter`, here's the one-way version:

```
public class PolynomialConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public DoubleCollection Coefficients { get; set; }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        double x = (double)value;
        double output = 0;
        for (int i = Coefficients.Count - 1; i >= 0 ; i--)
            output += Coefficients[i] * Math.Pow(x, (Coefficients.Count - 1) - i);

        return output;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        //This one is a bit tricky, if anyone feels like implementing this...
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

Examples:

```
<!-- x^2 -->
<vc:PolynomialConverter Coefficients="1,0,0"/>
<!-- x + 5 -->
<vc:PolynomialConverter Coefficients="1,5"/>
<!-- 2x + 4 -->
<vc:PolynomialConverter Coefficients="2,4"/>
```

---

Alternatively one could use the ConverterParameter instead to not set the Coefficients in the converter itself.

```
DoubleCollection coefficients = DoubleCollection.Parse((string)parameter);
//...
```