# Basic Mathematical Operations in XAML

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, vb.net, xaml

Is is possible to do basic mathematical operations like addition, division etc. in XAML?

For example, I want to set the height of a button to `{Binding ElementName=MW,Path=Height}/2`.

Comment: That's what your viewmodel is for. Do your maths there.

Comment: When you're using XAML you want to have a class that deals with the interaction between your view (the XAML GUI) and your "back end" model. That's your ViewModel. I don't know what it is you're trying to do exactly so I can't tell you how to do it but normally you would have a property on your ViewModel that calculates the desired height and then bind to that. What exactly is it you're doing? Maybe there's a better way of laying it out?

Comment: So you have 2 columns that you want to each take up half the space of their container? Sorry if I'm not understanding - I would rarely set the height or width of anything directly as it would normally just resize to fit whatever space it has.

Comment: I do not think the view model is a good place for this kind of operations either. Value converters are the best way to separate this concern into an isolated unit which is easy to debug, maintain and re-use.

Comment: You're probably right Murven. Trying to size columns like that isn't really what the viewmodel is for. A Value Converter that binds to the Width and halves it would be perfect for this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you change a bound value, reverse it, multiply it, subtract from it or add to it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4969600/how-do-you-change-a-bound-value-reverse-it-multiply-it-subtract-from-it-or-ad)

Comment: In WPF classes are the native way to do calculation.  XAML is just for laying out the page.   Some page type calculations might be appropriate in the viewmodel but for the most part that is what a converter is for.  What is wrong with a converter?

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question: No, it is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

My advice would be to create a [value converter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx) and apply them using [bindings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx), for any mathematical operations you want to perform. The view is definitely not the place to perform mathematical operations, you want to have that concern separated and isolated in a different class, so that it is easier to debug and maintain.

Answer (score 1):

Not possible without using a converter or a view model that does the conversion for you. For a generic converter, see `ExpressionConverter` in my [WPF Converters](http://wpfconverters.codeplex.com) project.