# How to do calculation in xaml while binding?

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding

I can bind a label to a slider as shown below:

```
<Label Name="lblTest" Content="{Binding ElementName=slider1, Path=Value}"/>
```

How do I bind another label to the same slider with display value of, say, 30% of the value of slider? How do I do the calculation in xaml and not in my code? Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you change a bound value, reverse it, multiply it, subtract from it or add to it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4969600/how-do-you-change-a-bound-value-reverse-it-multiply-it-subtract-from-it-or-ad)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You cannot do the calculation in XAML, you could however apply some [converter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.converter.aspx) which does it for you.

This question might be relevant: [How do you change a bound value, reverse it, multiply it, subtract from it or add to it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4969600/how-do-you-change-a-bound-value-reverse-it-multiply-it-subtract-from-it-or-ad)

Answer (score 17):

There are already a few projects which bring expressions to Bindigs, e.g. see
[CalcBinding](https://github.com/Alex141/CalcBinding) or [QuickConverter](https://github.com/JohannesMoersch/QuickConverter).