# Coordinates in WPF Canvas

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, shapes

when defining coordinates for canvas shapes in XAML files, is it possible to do something like this:

```
<Canvas x:Name="myCanvas"
        DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"
        VerticalAlignment="Stretch">

    <Canvas.Background>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="White" Opacity="100" />
    </Canvas.Background>

    <Ellipse x:Name="ell1"
                Width="30"
                Height="30"
                Stroke="Black"
                StrokeThickness="1"
                Fill="Red" 
                Canvas.Left="100"
                Canvas.Top="50" />

    <Ellipse x:Name="ell2"
                Width="30"
                Height="30"
                Stroke="Black"
                StrokeThickness="1"
                Fill="Red" 
                Canvas.Right="100"
                Canvas.Top="50" />

    <Line Stroke="Black"
            StrokeThickness="1" 
            X1="ell1.Canvas.Right"                              *** look here ***
            Y1="ell1.Canvas.Top + ell1.Height/2"                *** look here ***
            X2="ell2.Canvas.Left"                               *** look here ***
            Y2="ell2.Canvas.Top + ell2.Height/2" />             *** look here ***

</Canvas>
```

Or the only way of doing it is through C#?

Thanks,
Massimo

Comment: Yes, but in C#.  No way of doing that in XAML?

Comment: You could probably bind the properties with MultiBindings and appropriate binding converters, but be aware that `Canvas.Right` is not set on `ell1`, and `Canvas.Left` not on `ell2`, so their values are `NaN`. You should use the properties that you've set and add/substract the ellipse width as needed

Comment: As a note, Opacity is a double value between 0 and 1, so you should set `Opacity="1"`. However, that is the default anyway, so you don't need to set the Opacity of your SolidColorBrush at all. Even simpler, set `<Canvas ... Background="White" />`

Comment: @user1738687 It is not possible unless at least you use [IValueConverter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter(v=vs.95).aspx). Possible duplicate of : [Calculation in XAML while binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8874404/how-to-do-calculation-in-xaml-while-binding)

Comment: @Default The answer you've linked won't help much, because here we would have bindings to attached properties, which use a different syntax. OP would also need to use MultiBindings with an appropriate multi-value converter. And one problem would remain. Although the Ellipses would move when the Canvas resizes, the Canvas.Right property wouldn't change and hence not update any binding.

Comment: @Clemens I didn't think of the *attached* - good comment

Comment: It is not clear to me from your question what the requirements are here. In your example, the ellipses are exactly the same size and are (apparently) connected by a straight line between. The answer from @Clemens posted below will achieve a similar result, but your code seems to imply a desire for a more general solution (i.e. to connect edges of ellipses placed anywhere). Please be more specific about what your goal actually is.

Comment: @PeterDuniho 525 is the width of the window including window border. The top level layout panel, i.e. the "client area" is smaller.

Comment: @Clemens: ah, thanks. The discrepancy is 15 pixels (well, 14.6), which is _much_ greater than what I'd estimate the width of the window border just looking at it. But maybe the border also includes the shadow effect, something I hadn't considered.

Comment: As another note, it would be simple to avoid the need for calculating the exact line end points at the circles, if you would simply draw the Line behind the Ellipses, i.e. put it before the Ellipses in XAML or set its ZIndex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can indeed bind to an attached property like this:

```
<Line ... X2="{Binding Path=(Canvas.Left), ElementName=ell1}" />
```

But there is no `+` or `/` operators defined in XAML so you will have to write some code to be able to set the `Y1` property to `50 + 30 / 2`.

After all XAML is a *markup* language and C# is a programming language.

Answer (score 0):

This should generate the desired result without too much hassle. You may have to adjust the Margin of the Grid.

```
<Grid DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Margin="100,50">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Ellipse Grid.Column="0" Width="30" Height="30"
             Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" Fill="Red"/>

    <Ellipse Grid.Column="2" Width="30" Height="30"
             Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" Fill="Red"/>

    <Rectangle Grid.Column="1" Fill="Black" Height="1"/>
</Grid>
```

This is even simpler:

```
<DockPanel DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Margin="100,50">

    <Ellipse DockPanel.Dock="Left" Width="30" Height="30"
             Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" Fill="Red"/>

    <Ellipse DockPanel.Dock="Right" Grid.Column="2" Width="30" Height="30"
             Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" Fill="Red"/>

    <Rectangle Fill="Black" Height="1"/>
</DockPanel>
```