# How to binding a control's property with some compute in XAML (WPF)?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

for example , if I want to draw a square, per side 50 px ,the code like this : `<Rectangle Width="50" Height="{Binding Path=Width,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Fill="Blue"/>`;
but if I want to let the height  always equals to half of width , the code is not correct :`<Rectangle Width="50" Height="{Binding Path=Width/2,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Fill="Blue"/>` , so how to do it in XAML ?

Comment: Write a Binding Converter

Comment: You cannot do the calculation in XAML, you could however apply some converter which does it for you. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8874404/how-to-do-calculation-in-xaml-while-binding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this.
Code behind:

```
public class MyConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return ((double)value)/2;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

And xaml:

```
<local:MyConverter x:key="MyConverter"/>



<Rectangle Width="50" Height="{Binding Path=Width,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}}" Fill="Blue"/>
```