# Is this binding valid for a ListView?

Tags: wpf, listview, data-binding

I am trying to bind the height of a list view according to the height of the Items and have set the MaxHeight property as:

```
MaxHeight="{Binding (ListView.View).ItemHeight*2, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
```

is this the right way to do it? I am not able to get the results.

Comment: No, it won't work. Use converters.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4969600/how-do-you-change-a-bound-value-reverse-it-multiply-it-subtract-from-it-or-ad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't seem to work. Add PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High to your binding to see the effective result of a binding.

Set it Like so :

```
{Binding Path=Foo, PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}

System.Windows.Data Warning: 87 : BindingExpression (hash=6270677): TransferValue - using fallback/default value 'Infinity'
System.Windows.Data Warning: 88 : BindingExpression (hash=6270677): TransferValue - using final value 'Infinity'
```

If you need to compute values, use a `Converter` and pass in the computation base values as `ConverterParameter`.

Comment: could you explain where to set PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High?