# Define ToolTip with several binding properties

Tags: wpf, binding, tooltip

This is my `Dodel`:

```
public string Name { get; set; }
public string Id { get; set; }
public string Age { get; set; }
public string Description { get; set; }
```

This is my `ListView` column:

```
   <GridViewColumn Header="Name">
        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock"
                               Text="{Binding Description}"
                               ToolTip="{Binding Description}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn>
```

So in case i want to see in my `ToolTip` all my properties for example:

```
name + "\n" + Id + "\n" + Age + + "\n" + Description
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I would have done for that:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate.Resources>
        <ToolTip x:Key="Tip">
            <TextBlock>
                <Run Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                <LineBreak/>
                <Run Text="{Binding Age, StringFormat='Age: {0}'}"/>
            </TextBlock>
        </ToolTip>
    </DataTemplate.Resources>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" ToolTip="{StaticResource Tip}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

I used `Runs` so you can Bind Name and other properties on after the other with complete customisation.

Comment: Where i need to put this DataTemplate ?

Comment: Look at your post and replace your `DataTemplate` with mine. Then change Binding to suit your `Dodel`.

Answer (score 1):

Why not add a new string type property to your Model and combine all of them in the constructor.

If you really want to do it this way, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4969600/how-do-you-change-a-bound-value-reverse-it-multiply-it-subtract-from-it-or-ad) may help you.

Comment: You can also change `ToolTip.Template` to  for example a `StackPanel` and put multiple `TextBlocks` into it (all bound to another property), but to be honest, creating a new property in your Model is much cleaner and easier to maintain solution.

Comment: i dont want to add another To.String because i using this ToString in another  controller, can i have code example how to use this multiple TextBlocks ? (where i need to defint this ToolTip.Template ?)